# Style Header Title Based on Column Cell Type

Tags: css

I have a table that is filled with cells with CSS classes **string** and **currency**. I want the headers of the **string** columns to be left aligned, and the headers of the **currency** columns to be right aligned.

**Is there a way to do this purely with CSS?**

In the following code, the **Strings** header would be left aligned and the **Currency** header would be right aligned, and it should know this by detecting the class type of the cells in that column.

**Note: All cells in a single column (under the header) will share the same class type. There is no mixing and matching.**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Strings</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="string">This is a string.</td>
        <td class="currency">100.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My idea is something like this:

```
table td.string thead th { // if cells in column are of string type
    text-align:left;
}

table td.currency thead th { // if cells in column are of currency type
    text-align:right;
}
```

I know the CSS above won't work, but is there some CSS trickery that will do something like this?

Comment: Are the columns alternating, meaning they go string, currency, string, currency, etc.? If so you could use something like: `th:nth-child(odd) {text-align:left;}` and `th:nth-child(even) {text-align:right;}`

Comment: Not necessary, no. I'm trying to avoid pseudo-selectors though because I have to support earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given note

```
Note: All cells in a single column (under the header) will share the same class type. There is no mixing and matching.
```

You can try this changes in your html and css to achive this.

Html:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="string">
                    Strings
                </th>
                <th>
                    Currency
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr class="currency">
            <td class="string">
                This is a string.
            </td>
            <td class="currency">
                100.00
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

css:

```
 .string 
        {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .currency
        {
            text-align: right;
        }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could just go about it this way.